# Connect to AWS RDS MySQL database instance with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, flask-sqlalchemy

For my Flask app, I want to use the Flask-SQLAlchemy extension to connect to a database instance I created on AWS RDS.

When I try to connect, the application times out and I get the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2003, "Can't
>   connect to MySQL server on
>   'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com'(60")

My Code Looks Like This:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
application = Flask(__name__)

application.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://{master username}:{db password}@{endpoint}/{db instance name}'
db = SQLAlchemy(application)

@application.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

The [Flask-SQLAlchemy documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/config.html#configuration-keys) says that the format of the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI for mysql database connections should look like this:

```
mysql://username:password@server/db
```

Additionally, I can check the AWS RDS console for information on my database instance. The console looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvIZv.gif).

Right now I am assuming that
"username" in SQLAlchemy refers to the "Master Username" in the AWS RDS console,
"server" in SQLAlchemy refers to the "Endpoint" in the AWS RDS console,
and "db" refers to the "Database Instance Name"

What am I doing wrong??

If someone could describe the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI for me with the AWS RDS console terms, that would completely solve the problem.

Comment: how can be used the same for a aws rotating secret key and if the secret key updates do we need to restart the application?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go to your AWS RDS console and choose your instance  -> DB Security Groups -> Click Default

and add a new CIDR as per the recommended IP range.

This is basically a firewall configuration which determines who can connect to the database instance.

You could set it as 0.0.0.0/0 so that firewall doesn't prevent you from accessing it from any host/network.

Comment: This answer is not very valid now since the interface in AWS has changed :(

Comment: update: goto vpc > then go to security group > inboud rules > add ip range to allow

Answer (score 5):

This is a valid path: EC2 dashboard -> Find network & security from left side panel -> Security groups.

[image: Security groups]

If you have a security group created, you may go to number 2.

1. Creating a new security group:

There you can name your security group and description.

VPC will probably be automatically created for you.

[image: Create security group window]

After creating it, select it from the list.

2. Set up inbound and / or outbound connections:

Here you can configure inbound connections rules.

[image: Inbound window]

On edit -> add rule you have default presets for easy configuration, for example HTTP on port 80.

[image: Edit inbound connection rules window]

I hope this helps everyone from now on.

- Due to security reasons, try to only allow trusted IPs and / or security groups needed.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you're creating a database name in the initial setup of the database under addition configuration unless AWS RDS won't create a database.

Comment: Otherwise, use a database management tool like DBeaver to connect to the RDS instance and create the database there.

Answer (score 2):

Since `AWS` interface has changed a lot so reposting the answer with updated interface.

1. Go to your `database instances`, click on your `DB identifier` for your db.
2. There you'll see `Connectivity & security`, in that click on `VPC security groups` under `Security`. There you'll see a list of security groups.
3. Now click on `Inbound Rules`, then on the right you'll see `Edit Inbound Rules`, click on that.
4. Your `Inbound Rules` should look like the picture below.

[image]

After adding these rules, just save them & try to connect, it should work.